# Spell check tool for layouts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spell-checking

Is there a built-in spell check tool in QGIS?

I know spell checking attribute data may be a waste of time; but I would expect a tool for layouts, just to ensure labels etc have a basic sort of check would be available.

Comment: coming in QGIS 3.6 > https://north-road.com/2019/01/14/on-custom-layout-checks-in-qgis-3-6-and-how-they-can-do-your-work-for-you/ "It’d even be possible to hook into one of the available Python spell checking libraries to write a spelling check!"